# walkback - seaside decorator isNil at startup

Tags: seaside, dolphin-smalltalk

I'm working my way to become more familiar with seaside on dolphin. I have successfully completed the todo app. Now I have started my own app using the todo app as a guide.

I am getting walkback (see below) in the session start. I have set my app up similar to the todo. One thing I do notice is that when I go back into seaside config the root class says "a JCBYCBi..." rather than "JCBYCBi...", which seems to say an INSTANCE is in config rather than a CLASS.

Any help welcome,

John

decoration
^ decoration contents   <== decoration isNil

addDecoration: aDecoration
"Add aDecoration to the receivers decoration chain. Answer the added decoration."

```
| previous current |
previous := nil.
current := self decoration.
[ current ~~ self and: [ self decoration: current shouldWrap: aDecoration ] ] whileTrue: [
    previous := current.
    current := current next ].
aDecoration setNext: current.
previous isNil
    ifTrue: [ self decoration: aDecoration ]
    ifFalse: [ previous setNext: aDecoration ].
^ aDecoration
```

createRoot
^ self rootDecorationClasses
inject: self rootClass new
into: [ :component :decorationClass |
component
addDecoration: decorationClass new;
yourself ]

Comment: i failed to note that the dolphin seaside port is based on ss3.0

Comment: solved - forgot a super initialize.